# How to reset three.js clock?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to reset the clock so that `clock.getElapsedTime()` gives me a new time from when I reset the clock (for example, useful when restarting a game level/scene the second time).

I am initiating `clock = new THREE.Clock();`   in `init()`, and in my game loop `update()`, I am using this clock. But when the game is over, I want to reset the clock (I am not initiating the level again and am just positioning the player back to the beginning so I am not initiating a new clock).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked into the '.getDelta()' method to see if it suits your needs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bad news: It's **impossible** to reset the `THREE.Clock` to zero time, as of [r73](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases), released Oct 2015. The explanation is below, and the only possible workarounds are at the end of this answer.

### The Problematic Design of Three.Clock Investigated in Depth

> The design of Clock is dangerous...
>
> *-- Mrdoob, [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5696#issuecomment-64971096)*

To understand the flaw(s) in `THREE.Clock` we must inspect [the source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Clock.js) to see how it works. We can see that in the [constructor for a Clock](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Clock.js#L9-L11), a few variables are instantiated, which at first glace looks like we can overwrite on our `Clock` instance to reset to zero:

```
this.startTime = 0;
this.oldTime = 0;
this.elapsedTime = 0;
```

However, digging a little deeper, we need to figure out happens when [`getElapsedTime()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Clock.js#L37) is called. Under the hood, it calls [`getDelta()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Clock.js#L44), which mutates `this.elapsedTime`, which means that [`getDelta` and `getElapsedTime` are dangerous, conflicting functions](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5696), but we still need to look closer at `getDelta`:

```
var newTime = self.performance.now();

diff = 0.001 * ( newTime - this.oldTime );
this.oldTime = newTime;
this.elapsedTime += diff;
```

This function is **referencing some unknown, implicit global variable, `self`,** and calling some odd function, `self.performance.now()`. Red flag! But let's keep digging...

It turns out Three defines a global variable, `self`, with a property `performance` with a method `now()` [in the "main" Three.js file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/317d6f66542ab63323c5dab6c7a4e9d08c07ca05/src/Three.js#L77-L91).

Stepping back to `THREE.Clock` for a moment, look how it calculates `this.elapsedTime`. It's based on the value returned by `self.performance.now()`. That seems innocent enough on the surface, except the true problem arises here. We can see that `self.performance.now()` [creates a true "private" variable](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/317d6f66542ab63323c5dab6c7a4e9d08c07ca05/src/Three.js#L81) in a closure, meaning no one in the outside world can ever see / access it:

```
( function () {
    var start = Date.now();
    self.performance.now = function () {
        return Date.now() - start;
    }
} )();
```

This `start` variable is the start time of the app, as returned in milliseconds from [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

That means that **when the `Three.js` library loads, `start` will get set to the value `Date.now()`.** To clarify, **simply including the `Three.js` script has global, irreversible side effects for the timer.** Looking back on the clock, we can see that the return value of `self.performance.now()` is used to calculate the current elapsed time of a `Clock`. Because this is based on the private, inaccessible "start time" of `Three.js`, it will always be relative to when **you include the `Three.js` script**.

### Workaround #1

Store `startTime = clock.getElapsedTime()` on your game/level start and making all your calculations relative to that. Something like `var currentTime = clock.getElapsedTime() - startTime` which is the only way to get the true absolute time from your scene load / start.

### Workaround #2

`Three.Clock` under the hood is really just a thin wrapper around [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now), which is an IE9+ available method. You're probably better off creating your own tiny abstraction around this to get a sane clock, with an easy to implement `reset()` method. If I find an `npm` package with this functionality, or make my own, I will update this answer.

### Workaround #3

Wait for the Three.js `Three.Clock` source code to be updated, possibly by me. Since there is an open ticket for it, a pull request to fix it will likely be accepted.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work Andy. I have created a jsbin [here] (https://jsbin.com/vikuvaceqi/3/edit?html,console,output). Please have a look. Clock should reset after 5 seconds, but the console.log output shows the clock doesn't.

Comment: That was exactly the problem I was having as well before I posted here. I even initiated a new clock on that variable in resetClock() thinking that might do the trick no matter how inefficient. clock = new Three.Clock();

Comment: Oh, I'm looking more at the source, this is poorly designed in Three, let me see if I can find a workaround...

Comment: @krikey I updated the answer, probably way more than necessary

Comment: @FélixSaparelli that would require more investigation to make sure it didn't have any side effects throughout the library, for example animations that rely on timing functions

Answer (score 0):

Save the time at the start of the game: `var gameStartTime = clock.performance.now()`, and calculate the run of time thereafter by subtracting `gameStartTime` from `clock.performance.now()` at any other point during the game, including its end. For example: `gameStartTime - gameStartTime` would equal zero, and `clock.performance.now() - gameStartTime` would give you the seconds or minutes since the game began.

Here's a reference to the [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) timer function in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**This will not reset the clock but it will generate a new clock object and assign the new value to the elapsedTime variable every 5 seconds:**

```
let clock = new THREE.Clock();

const animate = () => {
  let elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
  if (elapsedTime > 5) {
    clock = new THREE.Clock();
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple workaround I use to `start` `pause` and `reset` the runtime of my animation systems.

```js
let offsetTime = 0; // in milliseconds

let start = false;

function reset() {

    offsetTime = 0;    

    start = false;

}

function start() {
    
    if ( start ) return;

    offsetTime += performance.now();    

    start = true;

}

function pause() {
    
    if ( start ) return;

    offsetTime -= performance.now();    

    start = false;

}

const animationRuntime = performance.now() - offsetTime;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).